# Bookdown: Cross-reference figure with a custom link text

Tags: r, reference, r-markdown, markdown, bookdown

I would like to cross-reference a figure (PDF/PNG) *with a custom link text* in a report compiled with bookdown as *LaTex/PDF output*.

Figures can be easily referenced as numbers (i.e. see Figure [1](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/cross-references.html)) with `see Figure \@ref(fig:FOO-Figure)`, assuming the chunk label was "FOO-Figure".
The syntax for *custom link texts* recommended in the [bookdown book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/cross-references.html) unfortunately only works for links and headlines for me, and not for included (external) figures:

Neither `[custom link text](#fig:FOO-Figure)` nor `[custom link text](#FOO-Figure)` work in LaTex/PDF output.

Interestingly, the former works if the output format is HTML and references to `file:///Users/.../book/my-headline.html#fig:FOO-Figure` as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For LaTeX output, `[text](#ID)` won't work without furher ado.

An explanation:

````r
```{r yourfigure, fig.cap = "This is your Figure!"}
knitr::include_graphics("image.png")
```
````

The reference `\@ref(fig:yourfigure)` is resolved to `\ref{fig:yourfigure}`. This is fine because knitr ensures that the image is put in a float environment with this label.

However, `[this](#fig:yourfigure)` is resolved to `\protect\hyperlink{fig:yourfigure}{this}` which is a reference to an anchor that doesn't exist. However, we may generate this anchor manually. A workaround is

````r
```{r yourfigure, fig.cap = "This is your Figure!"}
knitr::include_graphics("image.png")
```
\hypertarget{fig:yourfigure}{}
````

Comment: Fabulous! Thank you so much @M.A.! I added the `\hypertarget{fig:yourfigure}{}` above the figure chunk, such that the figure is shown completely when clicking on the linked `[reference to the figure](#fig:yourfigure)`.